# Is $p_1p_2p_3\cdots p_i > p_{i+1}^2$?

Tags: number-theory

> Is it always true that $p_1p_2p_3\cdots p_i > p_{i+1}^2$ where $p_i$ are the prime numbers listed in increasing order and $i>3$?

I was wondering if this is true because it would seem to depend on the prime gap between $p_{i}$ and $p_{i+1}$. Testing a few examples seems like it is likely to be true.

Comment: There is always a prime between n and 2n. So it is sufficient to show p1...p_i is greater than 4(p_i)^2 ; p1....p_i-1 is greater than 4 p_i ; sufficently p1....p_i-1 is greater than 8p_(i-1) ; p1....p_i-2 is greater than 8 . This is true for large enough i and can be easily verified for small i .

Comment: @JacobWakem Your first sentence is Bertrand's postulate, which has a non-trivial proof. So there is some interest to avoid this and to give a more elementary proof  for the above inequality (which is possible, see the duplicate).